# Remove table definition from RichTextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, rtf

I have a RichTextBox control in my view. I'm using code-behind (UI logic only) to format the RTF within my RichTextBox which is working from a 'Format' button click event which instantiates a TextRange:

```
private void _btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);
    rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
    rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, "12");
    rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, "Arial");
    rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, "Normal");
    rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null);
 }
```

I want to also remove any tables within the RTF. Can I use the same approach maybe from the `Table` class to remove tables from my RichTextBox? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to climb down the `Blocks` and get the descendants 
of the `FlowDocument` and get all the `Tables` and then remove them from the its `Parent`.

Comment: @Hardgraf I believe there are limited blogs/answers on how to do this. Basically you want to do recursion on the children and descendants then remove it from its parent.

Comment: There must be an easier way to do this other than iterating over the Rtf  & removing all the 'trowd' tags etc...

Comment: Is your scenario pasting to `RichTextBox` and remove the `Tables`? Or you want the opposite?

Comment: Yes exactly, so I want the tables to be removed on user paste, just leaving the remaining text.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the formatting of the pasted data? Or just pure text

Comment: I need to keep it as Rtf, can't use the Clipboard.GetText() method as I'm including bullets & numbered lists in the RichTextBox formatting therefore need it as Rtf not plain text...

Comment: I noticed you can invoke myString = Clipboard.GetText(Dataformats.Rtf) which will give you the clipboard contents in Rtf but then I'd still have to iterate over the string and the Rtf string is way too complex...

Comment: I've worked with `FlowDocuments` heavily. There's no other way to achieve what you want other than manipulating the string or climbing down the child descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone is trying to achieve this I don't think it's possible. Maybe you can iterate over a simple table in an Rtf string and remove the tags but if you can't determine user input the Rtf is by far too complex. Therefore here's my solution (of sorts...)

```
    private void _btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {              
       TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);

      rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Table.BorderThicknessProperty, "3");
      rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Table.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);
     }
```

In the 'Format' button click event I've set table borders to Red. On my save back to the database method I've used this simple if statement:

```
private void SaveToDbCommandAction()
{
    if(PastedText.Contains("trowd"))
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Cannot save Article. Please remove pasted tables");          
    }
    else
    {
        SaveToDb(RTBText);
    }            
}
```

Therefore when the user pastes in a table they are warned via the red cell borders. This is particularly useful if they paste a table with invisible borders and can't actually see the table. The If statement then determines whether the Rtf string contains a 'trowd' tag therefore preventing the save.